# How to rewrite URL in next js config?

Tags: next.js

I have written a rewrite in next.js config as below and it works fine.

```
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/service/:path*",
      destination: "/services/:path*",
    },
  ]
}
```

The above means the URLs which are coming like /service/test should be redirected to /services/test meaning there is only 1 file which handles all these routes [...services].js

But I have another file contact.js which works with router /contact but I want the user to see the same file content for URLs such as /aboutus/contact and /uber/kontact and handle many more translated URLs, it works well if I put a redirect in next.js config like

```
async redirects() {
return [
    {
       source: "/entreprise/contactez-nous",
       destination: "/contact",
       permanent: true,
    },
  ],
}
```

But in the above solution the URL itself changes to /contact which I dont want, I want the user to see contact.js file content on many translated URLs, I tried the below in redirect section but its not working.

```
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/aboutus/contact",
      destination: "/contact",
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: So from earlier conversation. It seems you need to translate url. I suggest looking at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358848/how-to-translate-routes-with-nextjs-and-next-i18next